# Why are markers with SVG icons not showing up in Safari only?

Tags: svg, here-api, here-maps-rest

Here-maps markers with an SVG icon do not show up in the map on Safari only (works on all other browsers).  I am also using the icons outside of the map, and they display fine there.  The actual map is a canvas though, so perhaps that has something to do with it?

Tried adding a height, width, and version attribute to the SVG markup for the icons.

SVG icon markup:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1.25rem" class="svg-inline--fa fa-map-marker-alt" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
  <path d="M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0zM192 272c44.183 0 80-35.817 80-80s-35.817-80-80-80-80 35.817-80 80 35.817 80 80 80z" fill="#007bff"></path>
</svg>
```

Marker creation:

```js
const svgMarkup = ''; //The markup from above
const latitude = 47.6062;
const longitude = 122.3321;

const icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);
return new H.map.Marker({lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, { icon });
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091989/svg-viewbox-height-issue-on-ios-safari

Answer (score 5):

This is more related to webkit browser specification, so please check this post [SVG viewbox height issue on ios Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091989/svg-viewbox-height-issue-on-ios-safari) and try the below solution do let us know if still your issue persist.

```
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```